# JVM и Java программы

Tags: java

> Программы, написанные на языке Java, исполняет JVM (Java Virtual
>   Machine – виртуальная машина Java). JVM — это специальная программа,
>   которая умеет исполнять программы, написанные на языке Java.

Как понять исполнять?

Comment: Что именно вам непонятно?

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev исполнять слово, как именно исполнять? Не пойму слово испольнять, запускать или что?

Comment: Аналогично тому, как процессор **исполняет** инструкции.

Comment: @ArchDemon а можно по простому?)

Comment: Куда уж проще. На самом деле там много сложнее, чем в приведённой вами  цитате

Comment: Любая программа - это последовательность инструкций, которую что-то должны выполнить. Когда вы запускаете исполняемый файл (с расширение exe), содержащиеся в нём инструкции выполняет процессор. Запустить файл с расширением class так не получится, нужно запустить виртуальную машину Java и передать class-файл на выполнение ей.

Comment: Рекомендую прочитать учебник. Любой из них начинается с описания того, как это работает.